# webapp for unique url opening after id verification

Tags: google-apps-script

Okay so I have trying to put together a web app that communicates with google sheet to open specified url based on user ID. I don't know, the code looks right (as far as I can tell (which isn't far at all)) but when one uses the user interface to open url nothing happens. Please help?

I have files written in google script, html and java.

Below is the code for all three.

```js
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
Logger.log(doGet)
Logger.log(include)

function processForm(formObject){
  var sh_data ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...";
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sh_data);

  // get ID from the html ouput
  var sh_form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  var id = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent();

  // get the rows 2D array and the header array from the 'Data' sheet
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var [header, ...rows] = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

  // get a list of IDs and a list of URLs from the rows
  var ids = rows.map(x => x[header.indexOf('Response ID')]);
  var urls = rows.map(x => x[header.indexOf('Unique URL')]);

  // find the row with given ID among IDs
  var row = ids.indexOf(id);

  // if the row exists, show the dialog
  if (row > -1) { 
    var url = urls[row];
    showAnchor('CLIK HERE', url);
  }

  // or do something else if nothing found
  else {
    ss.toast('ID not found')
  }
  Logger.log(processForm)

}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Click on Link to Begin");
}
```

```css
<script>

  function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">UserID Details</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
                            
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your Google Apps Script, it seems that `formObject` is not used. And, from `var id = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent();` and `var row = ids.indexOf(id);`, I cannot understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. And also, I cannot understand `when one uses the user interface to open url nothing happens. Please help?`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike here is the link to web app user interface - https://rebrand.ly/ufe0gcu - user enters username e.g. username - AGCXIO30QWTpT5 - open its linked unique url which is - https://www.stackoverflow.com/ -. However, as you'll be able to see, when you enter the given user name the webapp doesn't open url from google sheets. Please forgive me if the code is messed up. I have zero knowledge and learning while I work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I apologize as I  don't know how to phrase this question in a technical way, but  I would like to know how do I get  webapp to open the  username's website after verifying the username in google sheets. And please, don't apologize, you gentlemen are are my leaders, I am learning from you.

Comment: @Tanaike  var id = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); is suppose to get the id from user interface. And var row = ids.indexOf(id); is suppose to find the matching url in the id row

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. In your situation, how do you run the script? Which is Web Apps or a dialog?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry my good friend, but it would seem like I am the one who is confused now, as I don't understand your question. please help?

Comment: However in an attempt to clarify further the Google script used is adapted from a script that was provide in a previous question of mine titled - Open a website after verifying a string (google appscript) -, where the user interface was inside the sheet where the data was written. however I have now endeavored to turn that into a webapp but now I am unable to make html and gs talk to each other. I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `however I have now endeavored to turn that into a webapp but now I am unable to make html and gs talk to each other. I think that's where the problem is.`, I think so. Unfortunately, a dialog cannot be opened from Web Apps. I think that this is the reason for your issue. But I'm not sure about your goal. So now I still have the situation I cannot still understand your question. I really apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike What can I do to fix this?`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. So I cannot answer to your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.